# Tooltip in jquery calendar for disabled dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-tooltip

I have created a calendar control using jquery ui with some restrictions on dates to be selected.
My requirement is to show a tooltip on disabled dates like "Sorry this date is not selectable"
.
Is there any way around on this?
PFB my code:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
  </script>  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js">
  </script> 
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: -0,
        maxDate: "+1M +2D",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "calendar.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: 'D dd MM yy',
        showAnim: "clip"
    });
    $("#datepicker").change(function () {
        updateDate();
    });
    $("#addDate").click(function () {
        addDaysToDate();
    });
    $("#subtractDate").click(function () {
        subtractDaysToDate();
    });
});

function updateDate() {
    var today = new Date();
    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
    var date2 = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');

    date2.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    tomorrow.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    if (date2.getTime() == today.getTime()) {
     //document.getElementById('datepicker').value=document.getElementById('datepicker').value+" (TODAY)";

       $('#datepicker').val($('#datepicker').val() + " (TODAY)");
    } else if (date2.getTime() == tomorrow.getTime()) {
    //document.getElementById('datepicker').value=document.getElementById('datepicker').value+" (TOMORROW)";

       $('#datepicker').val($('#datepicker').val() + " (TOMORROW)");
    } else {
        $('#datepicker').text("");

    }
}
function addDaysToDate() {
    var date2 = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date2);
    $('#datepicker').change();
}

function subtractDaysToDate() {
    var date2 = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() - 1);
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date2);
    $('#datepicker').change();
}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="image" id="subtractDate" src="datedecrementer.png" />
<input type="text" id="datepicker"  style="width:220px;border:0" />
<input type="image" id="addDate" src="dateincrementer.png" />



</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`beforeShowDay`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) event, it fits your needs. It allows you to return:

> A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array
>   with:
>
> - [ 0]: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
> - [ 1]: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation
> - [ 2]: an optional popup tooltip for this date The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.

In this case is not used the jQuery UI tooltip plugin, but a "regular" tooltip.

Code:

```
var disabledTool = new Date();
disabledTool.setDate(disabledTool.getDate() - 2);
disabledTool.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: -0,
        maxDate: "+1M +2D",
        showOn: "button",
        dateFormat: 'D dd MM yy',
        showAnim: "clip",
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var tooltipDate = "I'm DISABLED!!";
            if (date.getTime() == disabledTool.getTime()) {
                return [true, '', tooltipDate];
            } else {
                return [true, '', ''];
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/cQFKN/

Comment: Edward: i have a little doubt. my code is working fine in all browsers but in IE, date picker is not closing self after selecting date..Any idea?

Comment: It's weird it can be an IE bug, today I can't check it on IE, I'll take a look tomorrow (GMT +1)

Comment: I have found the bug.. please see my commented part in code. This is creating problem in IE, now it is working fine